# android.os.BaseBundle not mocked

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, android-espresso

I am trying to write unit test case for one of the static methods.

```
  protected static ScheduleCheck createScheduleCheck(Bundle extra){
      long assetId = extra.getLong(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_ASSET_ID);
      int hour = extra.getInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_HOUR);
      int minute = extra.getInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_MINUTE);
      int ampm = extra.getInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_AMPM);
      long landmarkId = extra.getLong(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_LANDMARK_ID);
      final ArrayList<Integer> weekday =
         extra.getIntegerArrayList(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_WEEK_DAY_LIST);
      final Set<Weekday> weekdaySet = convertWeedays(weekday);
      // Adjust hour.
      hour = hour + 12 * ampm;

      ScheduleCheck scheduleCheck = new ScheduleCheck();
      scheduleCheck.setAssetId(assetId);
      scheduleCheck.setTimeToFireInDisplayTimezone((int) FinderUtils.getTimeInSeconds(hour, minute));
      scheduleCheck.setLandmarkId(landmarkId);
      scheduleCheck.setWeekdaysToFireInDisplayTimezone(weekdaySet);
      return scheduleCheck;
   }
```

Unit test case:

```
public class ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest {
   private static final long ASSET_ID = 1L;
   private static final int HOUR = 10;
   private static final int MINUTE = 10;
   private static final int AM = 0;
   private static final int PM = 1;
   private static final long LANDMARK_ID = 10L;
   private static final ArrayList<Integer> calendarWeekday = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
   private static final Set<Weekday> weekdaySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Weekday.SUNDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.MONDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.TUESDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.WEDNESDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.THURSDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.FRIDAY,
                                                                              Weekday.SATURDAY));
   private Bundle extra;
   private ScheduleCheck scheduleCheck;

   @Before
   public void setup(){
      extra = new Bundle();
      extra.putLong(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_ASSET_ID, ASSET_ID);
      extra.putInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_HOUR, HOUR);
      extra.putInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_MINUTE, MINUTE);
      extra.putInt(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_SCHEDULE_CHECK_AMPM, PM);
      extra.putLong(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_LANDMARK_ID, LANDMARK_ID);
      extra.putIntegerArrayList(ScheduleCheckRecommendationService.EXTRA_WEEK_DAY_LIST, calendarWeekday);

      // Schedule check
      scheduleCheck = new ScheduleCheck();
      scheduleCheck.setAssetId(ASSET_ID);
      scheduleCheck.setTimeToFireInDisplayTimezone((int) FinderUtils.getTimeInSeconds(HOUR, MINUTE));
      scheduleCheck.setLandmarkId(LANDMARK_ID);
      scheduleCheck.setWeekdaysToFireInDisplayTimezone(weekdaySet);
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown(){

   }
   @Test
   public void testCreateScheduleCheckOk(){
      ScheduleCheck actualScheduleCheck = ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiver.createScheduleCheck(extra);
    // verification steps ...
    ...
    ...
   }
}
```

But when I try to run the test cases using the gradle command `./gradlew test` I get the following error.

```
    com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.services.ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest > testCreateScheduleCheckOk FAILED
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putLong in android.os.BaseBundle not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
            at android.os.BaseBundle.putLong(BaseBundle.java)
            at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.services.ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest.setup(ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest.java:39)

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

I tried to visit the link(http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked) provided in the error message and included the suggested solution but it didn't work at all and I got a completely different error.

```
com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.services.ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest > testCreateScheduleCheckOk FAILED
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()J
        at android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(Native Method)
        at com.locationlabs.util.debug.FifoLog.log(FifoLog.java:97)
        at com.locationlabs.util.debug.Log.delegatePrintln(Log.java:238)
        at com.locationlabs.util.debug.Log.doLog(Log.java:198)
        at com.locationlabs.util.debug.Log.i(Log.java:268)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.util.WMCache.getInstance(WMCache.java:52)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.model.persister.AbstractPersister.load(AbstractPersister.java:31)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.manager.AccountDataManager.cachedAccountData(AccountDataManager.java:32)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.util.DateUtil.getFinderTimezone(DateUtil.java:52)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.util.DateUtil.getFinderOffset(DateUtil.java:72)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.model.ScheduleCheck.setTimeToFireInDisplayTimezone(ScheduleCheck.java:295)
        at com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.services.ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest.setup(ScheduleCheckRecommendationReceiverTest.java:49)
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue and why I am getting this error.